# Upgrade DNN Community to Evoq Content

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am trying to upgrade from the free version of DNN (Community Edition, 7.01.02) to Evoq Content (paid, 7.02.00).

I unzip the install, Evoq_Content_07.02.00_Install.zip, over the top of my Community web site and after triggering the upgrade process by hitting the site, the upgrade succeeds. However, when I view the site after the upgrade, the site's a mess.

One issue seems to be that the HEAD tag is missing lots of goodness, like:

- references to stylesheets
- references to javascript libraries, including jquery

Is there a well-defined process for the upgrade that I'm missing? Or is this particular upgrade troublesome?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the UPGRADE package, not the INSTALL package when upgrading.

That being said, the StyleSheets and JS errors would most likely be a problem with your Skin if I had to guess, but I would start by trying the upgrade with the UPGRADE package instead.

Comment: i know this old thread , but i need some explanation for the dnn upgrade .. at moment my company using Community dnn 7.0.6 and plan to upgrade to dnn evoq content 8.5. according to your explanation i need download the evoq upgrade file and copy over my Community 7.0.6 folder ? while another question i'm not found the website folder under evoq content 8.5 source code , can you tell me why ?

Comment: Yes, download the UPGRADE package and work from there.


As for the Source package, I don't think DNN provides the Source code for Evoq?

Comment: yes , they did provide us the modules source codes but without the website folder. Once we updated from community to evoq (compiled) how to i make the changes to the custom pages i having in my site since there is no source code provide. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

I have done the upgrade from Community to Social.  Like Chris mentioned, you need to use the upgrade package, not the install.  After that though, you still have to do several configuration steps.

The upgrade will not configure the site like the installation package.  I suggest creating another environment with a full install of Evoq Social and copy(re-create) the pages/configurations from that environment to your upgraded environment.  Here are some of those items you need to copy:

- Game Admin page and Admin menu item
- User Profile / Activity Feed page
- User login skin token
- Any social module pages

By the way, I had a conversation with the DNN team and this was their suggestion.